# Site should be loaded after all jQuery loading? How?

Tags: jquery, performance

In my website, I made many elements hidden initially using jQuery like .hide() etc. But the problem is at the very beginning of page load that hidden elements are showing until all other jQuery loads. I want to show my site after loading all jquerys without using any preloader plugin.

Comment: just hide them with CSS first `display:none`

Comment: Yeah! It solved my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that 2 ways:

**first (and the best):**

add `display:none;`  with css to this hidden items.

**second:**

```
document.body.style.display = 'none';
```

at top of your file